# Boundary Placement in QGIS 3.x

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, labeling, boundaries, parallel

in ArcMap there is a great function for polygon labels - boundary placement. So at the boundary with a new polygon the labels of both polygons are displayed opposite each other.

[image]

Is it possible to do the same display in QGIS 3.x?

I found similar functions in QGIS but the labels are not displayed opposite each other.

[image]